# How to change a background depending on the current day

Tags: css, html, background-image

I what to know how to make a background change based on the day it is (so like for example on the 31st it goes to a Halloween picture then on the rest to a other background)P.S I what to try not use JavaScript as I don't like using JavaScript.

Comment: it will not possible with plain html/css, you need javascript/php or some other language to construct

Comment: Please read all the topics on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @Andrew ok then I didn't what to use JavaScript but if needed I will use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comments you said javascript would be ok, so here it is in javascript.

This will do it for you: https://jsfiddle.net/4p18mxg9/5/

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    function myFunction() {
    switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/')";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/')";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/')";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/')";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/')";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/')";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/')";
        break;
}
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is " + day;   


}
```

Comment: Gets the job done but if their is something less lengthy it will be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server-side function to do this.

For example

```
$date = date("d F"); 

if($date == "18 May"){ 
echo "style=\"background:rgba(0,0,0,1);\"" // don't forget to escape quotes and such 
}
```

Comment: This can also be done with javascript. No need for a server.

Comment: What programming language is that?

Comment: @Quentin that's `PHP`

Comment: PHP.
@Patrick2607 yes.

Comment: Ok I try later as 000webhost is not letting people sign in

Comment: It didn't work for me.